# Как найти координаты точки по середине между двумя другими точками?

Tags: javascript, карты, координаты

Всем привет!

Использую JS

У меня есть 2-(две) точки c координатами по широте и долготе

мне нужно найти точку между ними(по середине), а точнее ее координаты

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Comment: У меня есть два числа. Подскажите, как найти число посередине между ними.

Comment: Чем ближе к полюсу тем менее это верно. Задача немного сложнее.

Comment: Изучить что такое полярные координаты и как в них работать

Comment: "Полярные координаты" - термин для плоскости. Вы имели в виду сферические координаты?

Comment: Ну да, сферические. Просто для меня они по привычке все полярные независимо от размерности пространства.

Comment: Гуглите "Ортодромия" и все, что с ней связано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея решения: от координат вида `(широта, долгота)` перейти к точкам в прострастве `(x, y, z)`. Для двух таких точек посчитать среднее по формулам `((x1 + x2) / 2, ...)`. Из средней точки восстановить широту и долготу.

`midLatlon` решает задачу:

```js
const degToRad = a => Math.PI / 180 * a;
const radToDeg = a => 180 / Math.PI * a;

const latlonToXyz = latlon => {
    const [lat, lon] = latlon.map(degToRad);
    return [
        Math.cos(lat) * Math.cos(lon),
        Math.cos(lat) * Math.sin(lon),
        Math.sin(lat)
    ];
};

const xyzToLatlon = xyz => {
    const [x, y, z] = xyz;
    return [
        Math.atan2(z, (x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** 0.5),
        Math.atan2(y, x)
    ].map(radToDeg);
};

const midXyz = (xyz1, xyz2) => [
    (xyz1[0] + xyz2[0]) / 2,
    (xyz1[1] + xyz2[1]) / 2,
    (xyz1[2] + xyz2[2]) / 2
];

const midLatlon = (latlon1, latlon2) => xyzToLatlon(midXyz(
    latlonToXyz(latlon1),
    latlonToXyz(latlon2)
)); 

const test = (latlon1, latlon2) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify([latlon1, latlon2, midLatlon(latlon1, latlon2)]));
};

test([60, 45], [60, 45]); 
test([60, 45], [61, 46]); 
test([0, 90], [90, 0]); 
test([80, 90], [80, -90]);
```

Answer (score 0):

x = (x1+x2)/2
y = (y1+y2)/2

Отличия от координат на плоскости никаких нет

Comment: Для координат `[0, 90]` и `[90, 0]` средняя точка совсем не `[45, 45]`.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy и координаты [90, 0] в географических координатах нима. )) Тупо 90 градусов северной или южной широты.

Answer (score 0):

Просто представте эту линию как гипотенузу в треугольнике с катетами.
Первый катет (x2 + x1)/2, второй (y2 + y1)/2, это и есть координаты, на пересечении которых будет середина гипотенузы.

Comment: "представь эту линию как треугольник" - ??

Comment: Для примера, треугольник с координатами (0, 0), (0, 90 в.д.), (90 с.ш) - октант, в котором почти вся Европа лежит. Есть три линии, три угла - каждый по 90 градусов. Какую линию представим гипотенузой? ))) И координаты середин сторон будут (0, 45) (45 с.ш, 0) и (45 с.ш, 90). У следующего октанта: (0, 90 в.д.), (0, 180), (90 с.ш)  - середины: (45, 90), (0, 135 в.д.) и (45 с.ш, 180). И т. д. Отдельного отрезка с коорд. (90 с.ш.) (90 ю.ш) нима. Тут нужно долготу задавать или же "центром" будет весь экватор.

Comment: Я не понимаю как в треугольнике три угла по 90 градусов)) а в целом, согласен, не обратил внимание, что речь идёт о карте, а не об обычной плоскости.

Answer (score -1):

Просто полусуммы не дадут нужный результат, т.к. нужно учитывать полушария.

При проектировании геоида на плоскость, в соответствии с используемой картографической проекцией, в свое время учитывал в представлении знаков декартовой плоскости:

```
СВ = (+,+), СЗ = (-,+), ЮВ = (+,-), ЮЗ = (-,-)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).